# Zend submit button position

Tags: php, html, zend-framework

I have two forms that I'm calling from elements from the same controller, the second one is wrapped in an HTML table, I want to know how can I position my submit button at the bottom, after my table, because right now it's in the middle of the first form and the table.

I tried to assign the element in my controller and echo it in the view but it's still at the same position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that:

1 -  for each form give a name like `$this->setName('name1');` for example

2 - remove the submit button of your forms

3  - create a button in your view where you want:

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Validate" onClick="subForm()">
```

4 - In js create subForm() function:

```
<script>
    function subForm(){
        document.forms['name_of_your_form'].submit();
    }
</script>
```

Of course, you can switch to the parameter name of the form you want to send.